# R extract text until, and not including x

Tags: r, regex

I have a bunch of strings of mixed length, but all with a year embedded. I am trying to extract just the text part, that is everything *until* the number start and am having problem with lookeahead assertions assuming that is the proper way of such extractions.

Here is what I have (returns no match):

`>grep("\\b.(?=\\d{4})","foo_1234_bar",perl=T,value=T)`

In the example I am looking to extract just `foo` but there may be several, and of mixed lengths, separated by `_` before the year portion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will grab everything up until the first digit

```
x <- c("asdfas_1987asdf", "asd_das_12")
regmatches(x, regexpr("^[^[:digit:]]*", x))
#[1] "asdfas_"  "asd_das_"
```

Answer (score 5):

Look-aheads may be overkill here. Use the underscore and the 4 digits as the structure, combined with a non-greedy quantifier to prevent the 'dot' from gobbling up everything:

```
/(.+?)_\d{4}/
```

-first matching group ($1) holds 'foo'

Answer (score 2):

Another approach (often I find that strsplit is faster than regex searching but not always (though this does use a slight bit of regexing):

```
x <- c("asdfas_1987asdf", "asd_das_12") #shamelessly stealing Dason's example
sapply(strsplit(x, "[0-9]+"), "[[", 1)
```

Comment: I can't blame you for stealing my example - I spent a long time thinking about the perfect combination of mashed together keys to make that example.

Comment: I'm being punished for the thievery as no one appreciates the `strsplit` answer and it was some of my best work too :)  It's Sunday night and I'm bored so I may bench the 3 examples to drum up support for my answer.  Though I may lack the motivation to even do that.

Comment: I'm a bit worried that you have the "+" inside the character class brackets. (Actually now that I've tested, I am more than worried.) Should be strsplit(x, "[0-9]+")

Comment: @DWin fixed it is that better?  I usually wind up playing with regex until I get it to do what I want or go read the manual do the task and promptly forget how for next time :(